# How to implement JavaScript in master page of SharePoint 2013 and JavaScript files are not loading in masterpage

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Custom `Quick launch` comes from the master page and visible through out the entire site. I used CSS to hide quick launch in some of the pages, But it shows up to the all document libraries and is everywhere. So I want to show the quick launch to only pages from the pages library and  want to achieve this using javascript in `master page`, but the script files are not loading in masterpage. 
Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console? How did you reference the script files within the masterpage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can upload your `JavaScript` file in the `Style Library` and use the `SharePoint:Scriptlink` tag in Master Page to load it.

**For example**:

If you have a js file called `YourScriptName.js`. Goto `Site Contents -> Style Library`, create a folder for your custom scripts to lie, and upload the one which you want to use.

Then open up your master page and in the header section add a `Scriptlink` tag to load the `js` file.

```
<SharePoint:Scriptlink ID="Scriptlink9" runat="server" name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/YourFolderName/YourScriptName.js" language="javscript" />
```

The above tag goes in `Master Page`.

Comment: Thank you Asad. I tried your tag and it is working fine now at the site collection level. But my javascript files are in site assets of a subsite.How to change the reference to subsite level.

Comment: how can i add this in seattle.html?

Comment: @vignesh https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/211734/referring-js-file-within-a-master-page-html-page-did-not-work?noredirect=1&lq=1