# Hiding permission button on ribbon SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

I'm new to SharePoint 2019. When configuring permission for a specific item in list/task, I would like to hide one or more button in ribbon.

[image]

Do you know how to do it by code or configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You could add CSS code to hide the button. Note that the CSS selector used should not affect other pages.

[image]

[image]

Or you could add js code to hide the button.
[how-to-implement-javascript-in-master-page-of-sharepoint-2013-and-javascript-fil](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163448/how-to-implement-javascript-in-master-page-of-sharepoint-2013-and-javascript-fil)

Tip: You'd better create a new master page to do the test.

[How to Create a Custom Master Page Using Design Manager in SharePoint 2016 – Step by Step](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/08/how-to-create-custom-master-page-using-design-manager-in-sharepoint-2016.html)

[Customize A SharePoint 2013 Master Page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7GM6Fnz_H4&ab_channel=kalmstrom.com)